# Why the callback of getJSON function doesn't executed?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I found that jquery has a solution for **CORS**

here's the code in the js file:

```
   $.getJSON('http://localhost:8001/location?callback=?', function(data){
        console.log(data[]);
        console.log("anything");

    });
```

the server json API: for the `http://localhost:8001/location?callback=?` request, return

({url:'bar'})

The problem is the `console.log()` never executed, I put break point in there, but the browser doesn't stop there.

PS the cross domine request is successful, because I can see the responds json file is in the resources list in the web inspector

Any idea?

Comment: The response should be wrapped inside function. Function name should be same as callback name.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao: No, jQuery handles that plumbing. jQuery defines the function, receives the callback, and then calls the success function.

Comment: *"I found that jquery has a solution for CORS"* While JSONP is cross-origin resource sharing in the general sense, I would avoid calling it CORS, as that's easily misread as the quite different [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) technology.

Comment: Have you check your console?

Comment: @roasted Yes I did. there's no console output

Answer (score 3):

Well, the code as presented in the question won't run at all (it won't even make the request), because it has a syntax error:

```
console.log(data[]);
// Here --------^^
```

But I assume from your saying you've seen the response that you must have tested without that error at some point.

Your server response is incorrect. You've said

> the server json API: for the `http://localhost:8001/location?callback=?` request, return
>
> `({url:'bar'})`

...but that's not a valid JSONP response (it's also not a valid JSON response, in three different ways). To form the correct JSONP response, you have to respond with a JavaScript function call using the function name you receive in the `callback` query string parameter. So for instance, if `callback` is `__jquery456481345`, then the response should be:

```
__jquery456481345({"url":"bar"})
```

---

About JSON: I've said above that `({url:'bar'})` is not a valid JSON response in three different ways. Again, in your example you're using JSONP (which is different), but just for completeness, here are the problems with that as JSON:

1. A JSON document cannot start with `(`, it must start with `{` or `[`.
2. In JSON, property names (keys) **must** be in double quotes, e.g. `"url": ...`, not `url: ...`.
3. In JSON, strings **must** be in double quotes, single quotes are not valid like they are in JavaScript. So `"bar"`, not `'bar'`.